# How to replace first n1 and last n2 rows with NA in specific columns

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following example:

```
library(data.table)
mat <- data.table(x = c(1:10), y = c(11:20), z = c(21:30))

cut.head <- c(0, 2, 1) 
cut.tail <- c(3, 1, 2)
```

`cut.head` represents the number of rows that each column will be NA from top.

`cut.tail` represents the number of rows that each column will be NA from last.

For example, if `cut.head` is used, 1st and 2nd rows of column y will be NAs, as well as the 1st column of z

I would like the return as follows:

```
     x  y  z
 1:  1 NA NA
 2:  2 NA 22
 3:  3 13 23
 4:  4 14 24
 5:  5 15 25
 6:  6 16 26
 7:  7 17 27
 8: NA 18 28
 9: NA 19 NA
10: NA NA NA
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use a `for` loop with `:=` (or `set()`) so it's fast and (fairly) easy to read.

```
> for (i in 1:3) mat[seq_len(cut.head[i]), (i):=NA]
> mat
     x  y  z
 1:  1 NA NA
 2:  2 NA 22
 3:  3 13 23
 4:  4 14 24
 5:  5 15 25
 6:  6 16 26
 7:  7 17 27
 8:  8 18 28
 9:  9 19 29
10: 10 20 30
```

Notice that the LHS of `:=` accepts column numbers as well as names. As an aside, this is valid :

```
DT[, 2:=2]   # assign 2 to column 2
```

Wrapping the LHS of `:=` with parenthesis, `(i):=NA`, tells it to use the variable's value rather than its name.

For the tail I first tried the following but `.N` isn't available in `i`. I've added that as a feature request, [FR#724](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/724).
**UPDATE**: Now added to v1.9.3 on 11 Jul 2014

```
for (i in 1:3) mat[.N+1-seq_len(cut.tail[i]), (i):=NA]
# .N now works in i
> mat
     x  y  z
 1:  1 NA NA
 2:  2 NA 22
 3:  3 13 23
 4:  4 14 24
 5:  5 15 25
 6:  6 16 26
 7:  7 17 27
 8: NA 18 28
 9: NA 19 NA
10: NA NA NA
>
```

We no longer have to live with a repetition of the symbol `mat` :

```
> for (i in 1:3) mat[nrow(mat)+1-seq_len(cut.tail[i]), (i):=NA]
```