# How do you extract a few random rows from a data.table on the fly

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a large data.table (about 24000 rows and growing). I want to subset that datatable based on a couple of criteria and from that subset (ends up being about 3000 rows) I want to randomly sample just 4 rows. I do not want to create a named 3000 or so row data.table, count its rows and then sample based on row number. How can I do it on the fly? Or should I just suck it up by creating the table and then working on it, sampling it and then using `rm()` to get rid of it?

Lets simulate my issue

```
require(data.table)
random.length  <-  sample(x = 15:30, size = 1)
data.table(city=sample(c("Cape Town", "New York", "Pittsburgh", "Tel Aviv", "Amsterdam"), size=random.length, replace = TRUE), score = sample(x=1:10, size = random.length, replace=TRUE))
```

That makes a random length table, which simulates the fact that depending on my criteria and depending on my starting table, I do not know what the length of the subsetted table with be

Now, if I just wanted the first three rows I could do as so

```
data.table(city=sample(c("Cape Town", "New York", "Pittsburgh", "Tel Aviv", "Amsterdam"), size=random.length, replace = TRUE), score = sample(x=1:10, size = random.length, replace=TRUE))[1:3]
```

But let us say I did not want the first three rows but rather a random 3 rows, then I would want to do something such as this...

```
data.table(city=sample(c("Cape Town", "New York", "Pittsburgh", "Tel Aviv", "Amsterdam"), size=random.length, replace = TRUE), score = sample(x=1:10, size = random.length, replace=TRUE))[sample(x= 1:number of rows of that previous data.table,size = 3 ]
```

That  will not work. How do I compute, on the fly, what the length of the initial data.frame was?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Have just made `.N` work in `i`. New README item :

> `.N` is now available in `i`, [FR#724](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/724). Thanks to newbie indirectly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24649115/403310) and Farrel directly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685421/how-do-you-extract-a-few-random-rows-from-a-data-table-on-the-fly).

This now works :

```
DT[...][...][sample(.N,3)]
```

e.g.

```
> random.length  <-  sample(x = 15:30, size = 1)
> data.table(city = sample(c("Cape Town", "New York", "Pittsburgh", "Tel Aviv", "Amsterdam"),size=random.length, replace = TRUE), score = sample(x=1:10, size = random.length, replace=TRUE))[sample(.N, 3)] 
         city score
1:   New York     4
2: Pittsburgh     3
3:  Cape Town     9
>
```

Comment: Darn, darn good. Thank you. That's just what I wanted. I realized I had to go install the latest version from GitHub. I ran into problems with `pdflatex is not available`. I read somewhere about the build_vignettes=F argument and all worked well after that. `install_github("data.table", "Rdatatable", build_vignettes=F)`

Comment: why not just `DT[sample(.N,3)]`?

Comment: @ufos the `[...][...]` part was just to convey the general case of when used in chaining, the `.N` refers to the last part of the chain (not the original `DT` at the beginning of the chain). That general case covers  `DT[sample(.N,3)]` too.

Comment: @MattDowle how do you sample without replacement?

Comment: @HermanToothrot `sample(.N,3)` is already sampling without replacement. To sample with replacement, `sample(.N,3,replace=TRUE)`.  See `?sample`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a two step approach:

1. Compute the index `i` using `.I`
2. Sample on index `i`

Example code.

```
require(data.table)
random.length  <-  sample(x = 15:30, size = 1)
data.table(city = sample(c("Cape Town", "New York", "Pittsburgh", "Tel Aviv", "Amsterdam"),size=random.length, replace = TRUE), score = sample(x=1:10, size = random.length, replace=TRUE))[,i := .I][sample(i, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative way would be to use `sapply` approach. 
 
  For example:

```
  as.data.table(sapply(DT[], sample, 10))
```

Comment: nice, thanks. But note that this does not preserve the data type. I get every column transformed into numeric.