# sample from data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have some data.table from which I want to select a random subset, but only for some operations.

Suppose the data is

```
dat <- data.table(id=1:100, group=sample(1:20,100, replace=TRUE), a=runif(100), b=rnorm(100))
```

and I want to do two things:

1. count the number of ids per group
2. select from each group one id at random and record its value on `a` and `b`

I could follow [How do you extract a few random rows from a data.table on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685421/how-do-you-extract-a-few-random-rows-from-a-data-table-on-the-fly) and choose

```
dat[n=.N, a=a[sample(.N,1)], b=b[sample(.N,1)], group]
```

but I am afraid, this will select `a` and `b` independently from one another. Is there a way of selecting the same?

Comment: use {} in j to do multiple expressions -- first, select an index by sample()ing from .I, then apply this random index to both vectors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Part 1

If you want to count the number of unique ids and some ids repeat within groups

```
dat[, .(n_ids = uniqueN(id)), group]
```

If ids don't repeat within groups or you don't want to count them on a unique basis

```
dat[, .(n_ids = .N), group]
```

## Part 2

If ids repeat within groups and you want to return all rows for the randomly selected id in each group

```
dat[dat[, .(id = sample(id, 1)), group], on = .(id, group)]
```

If ids do not repeat, or you only want one row per group anyway

```
dat[dat[, sample(.I, 1), group]$V1]
```

---

Thanks to Frank's comment, you can also do the second option for parts 1 & 2 above in one line. This returns the row like `dat[dat[, sample(.I, 1), group]$V1]` but also adds a column `N` showing the number of ids (assumed to equal the number of rows in the group)

```
dat[sample(.N), c(.SD[1], .N), keyby=group]
```

Comment: Another way: `dat[sample(.N), c(.SD[1], .N), keyby=group]`